# Change application to be launched using Voice Action

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, music-player, voice-command

Is there a way I can change which app will launch upon Voice action? For example when I say "Listen to Pink Floyd", it currently opens Last.fm app which is more or less useless for me since Last.fm doesn't have streaming in my location.

Can I configure it to open, say, Winamp instead of Last.fm? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe if you uninstall the Last.fm app, then use the Voice Action "Listen to..", a pop up should show asking which of the default players listed [here](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186172), will show up and be used.

If however, you'd prefer the default in-built player to play, use [Listen To](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.bakachu.listento) or the app [Choice Dialer](http://choicedialer.com/), available in both free and paid versions in the market.

Comment: If I choose to uninstall last.fm, my scrobbles will not be recorded - I don't want that. BTW - why did you mark the answer as CW ?

Comment: OK, You didn't mention that Last.fm was a requirement. BTW, Meridian Player supports scrobbling (with help from scrobbledroid) if you want to take a look at it.

Community Wiki because I felt this question could benefit from other users editing it (even if they didn't have sufficient editing privileges).

Comment: Just had a look-see and Winamp seems to [support scrobbling](http://www.winamp.com/help/Main_Page#Scrobbling) too, via the official Last.fm app.

Comment: @Sparx sorry I should've mentioned it explicitly in the question. Winamp supports scrobbling, but requires the last.fm app which results in the question I posed.

Comment: Have you tried the apps I mentioned?

Comment: For scrobbling from various players without the official last.fm app, I use this: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adam.aslfms&hl=en

Answer (score 5):

You can clear the preferred program from "Settings > Applications > Manage applications > Last.FM > Clear defaults"

Then the next time you launch the Voice Action, you'd be prompted with a list of players, click on the "Make default" then on your new preferred application.

Comment: Clear defaults is disabled, says `No defaults set`